# my template is broken and cannot get static files

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

my template didn't work and can't get static files but I did everything.
my static folder is in the Base directory but when I'm trying to reach static files, for example, CSS or js I'm getting file not found error and template is broken.
my file Tree for project

[this is an image of my folder and project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G8x1.png)

Settings for Static and media.

```
STATIC_URL = '/temfiles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/uploads/')
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

my project URL file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('froala_editor/', include('froala_editor.urls'))

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my app URL file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='Post Detail')
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my Views File

```
def index(request):
    Post_list = BlogPost.objects.all()
    template_name = 'front/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name,{"Post_list":Post_list})



def post_detail(request):
    return render(request, 'front/post_detail.html')
```

my base template CSS example

```
   {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
  'front/css/style.css' %}">
```

[Static Directory Tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58mG5.png)

[static directory tree with open folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK5d6.png)

[browser inspect terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cZHB.png)

[style CSS URL in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAsz.png)

[MY urls.py for static and media root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhZZR.png)

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: from manage.py run server in localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: why you have `STATIC_URL = '/temfiles/'` instead of `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: I change it everything works but except style.css it's not loading says file not found but this file is in folder like others and other files are loading except this style.css

Comment: @GeorgeVTheDeveloper post  file tree of static folder, just like you did above, make sure all the folders in static are open .

Comment: I add sir static directory tree hope you will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both debug-time url patterns for static and media:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: not working I can't add both of them getting a syntax error in terminal

Comment: try splitting into multiple statements

Comment: still not working (((( i try with if Debug and without it, I will add picture

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Use text.

Answer (score 0):

this didn't work because when Django using DEBUG he's looking static files into the application folder, so after debug is turned off it's will get everything from the Base directory where is static files path written. so in debug, you should collect static in the app folder and after this, you must use command collect static and Django terminal will fix this before uploading on global